# FluentValidation not working for a null property

Tags: c#, wpf, fluentvalidation, idataerrorinfo

I'm using `FluentValidation` with `IDataErrorInfo`, and I have a validator defined as follows:

```
public class StsInfoValidator : AbstractValidator<StsInfo>
{
    public StsInfoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeProperty).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
            .NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("SomeProperty is required.");

    }        
}
```

However, passing in a `null` property doesn't seem to trigger the validator:

```
#region IDataErrorInfo

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {

        var validator = new StsInfoValidator();

        if (columnName.Equals("SomeProperty"))
        {
            // SomeProperty below is null
            if (validator.Validate(this, SomeProperty).Errors.Any())
                return validator.Validate(this, CampusNexusApiServer).Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage;
            else
            {
                validator = null;
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: There are FallbackValue or TargetNullValue for a Binding that cater to the scenario when a Binding returns Null
Also can you explain a little more what do you mean by Null Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that if you choose to use the `Validate` overload that requires a lambda expression to evaluate your property you'll have to do:

Instead of:

`validator.Validate(this, SomeProperty);`

you need:

`validator.Validate(this, s => s.SomeProperty);`

Here this overload documentation:

[image]

Alternatively you can use the other `Validate` overload and pass the name of your property as a string:

`validator.Validate(this, columnName);` or
`validator.Validate(this, "SomeProperty");`

Here is the property Name(s) overload for Validate:

[image]

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {

            var validator = new StsInfoValidator();

            if (columnName.Equals("SomeProperty"))
            {
                // SomeProperty below is null
                //option 1
                var result  = validator.Validate(this,s => s.SomeProperty);
                //option 2
                //var result  = validator.Validate(this, columnName);
                //option 3
                //var result  = validator.Validate(this, "SomeProperty");
                if (result.Errors.Any())
                    return validator.Validate(this, CampusNexusApiServer).Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage;
                else
                {
                    validator = null;
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```